# How to get the value of a range within a range

Tags: vba, excel, range

So I need to extract information from a sheet with only certain values. From about 550 rows down to 50 which are spread across the entire sheet.

So I used autofilter for that. Now I only see the rows which match to my criteria but how can I get the values of a specific range from?

This far I came:

I know that I have to use

```
RangeINamed.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

to work with only the visible information.
It worked for getting the starting and last row

```
startRow = bulkbatchRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).row
endRow = startRow + bulkbatchRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).rows.Count
```

But now I need to get the value of a specific column, I want to use a For loop so I can loop through all visible rows.

So I tried to do

```
RangeINamed.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).range("U" & rowNumber).value
```

That didn't work it gave me nothing. Now I'm rather clueless so does someone maybe know how I get the value of that row in column U in RangeINamed?

Thank you

Comment: RangeINamed.Range("U10").value or Sheets("MySheetName").Range("U10")

Comment: Hm jeeh, sorry I wasn't specific enough but I don't have the exact rownumber. So I can't specify it like "U10". All I know is the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always retrieve the value in a specific cell like **U10** with:

```
Range("U10").Value
```

whether the row is hidden or not.

**EDIT#1**:

Here is a little example that loops down thru column A of an AutoFiltered table.  It looks for the third visible row (*not including the header row*):

```
Sub GoDownFilter()
    Dim rLook As Range, r As Range
    Set rLook = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
    rLook.Select
    K = 0
    For Each r In rLook
        If K = 3 Then
            r.Select
            MsgBox "The third visible row has been selected"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        K = K + 1
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't really clear about that. But I don't know the rownumber (I want to use a For loop for only the visible rows) because of the visibility it sometimes jump from row 10 to row 40. So I can't directly specify "U10"

Comment: Hi:  Xepos, would you like to see how to loop down an AutoFiltered column??

Comment: Yes! That's what I'm trying to do I think.

Comment: Yes that for loop is exactly what I wanted to have thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to choose if you want to get a specific cell like:

`Range("U10").Value`

Or a relative cell using something like

```
RangeINamed.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(2,3).Value
```

Or

```
RangeINamed.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(2,3).Address 'To see if you are getting it right
```

**EDIT:**

A complete code to Filter and Iterate.

```
Sub Filter()
Dim tableRange As Range, var, actualRow As Integer, lastRow As Integer

Set tableRange = Range("PUT_THE_TABLE_RANGE_HERE")

' Filter 
With tableRange
    Call .AutoFilter(5, "SPECIFIC_FILTER")
End With

Set f = tableRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

With tableRange
    Call .AutoFilter(5)
End With

For Each var In f.Cells.Rows
    actualRow = var.Row
    If actualRow <> 1 Then
        ' Do something
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. Didn't know you could place another range just like that.